# What is the QGIS installation type and OSGeo4W?

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

There are standalone last release and long term release among QGIS installation types on the QGIS homepage. However, there is one more OSGeo4W network installation file. What is this? Do I have to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OSGeo4W network installation file is a package used for advanced users to enable them to install several QGIS versions in parallel. For example, you can install QGIS long-term release (LTR) and the QGIS latest version at the same time. Also, you can install the nightly builds QGIS version which is used for testing and is not recommended for GIS projects because it may not be stable.

I am quoting the following paragraph from the [QGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html):

> The OSGeo4W repository contains a lot of software from OSGeo projects.
> QGIS and all dependencies are included, along with Python, GRASS,
> GDAL, etc. The installer is able to install from internet or just
> download all needed packages beforehand.